# How to prevent file corruption in SD card during unmount?

Tags: external-sd, data-corruption

I have a custom device running Android 8.1. I am mimicking a partition of the internal flash storage to be used as a removable storage.

At boot *vold* mounts the storage and creates the mount points. 
From an android app, I am able to use storage manager APIs to access the storage and perform operations such as mount, unmount, etc.

Problem is, occasionally, I am getting file corruptions on the SD card when unmounting. I am saying '***on unmounting***' because I see the files corrupted when the same partition is enumerated to computer as USB mass storage after unmounting.

I do make sure the files written to the card are 'flushed' and later a 'sync' is done on the shell as an extra precaution before unmounting the volume using the android storage manager APIs

Storage is available in android app at `/storage/D80A-0F16`.

```
/dev/block/vold/public:179,27 on /mnt/media_rw/D80A-0F16 type vfat (rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/mnt/media_rw/D80A-0F16 on /mnt/runtime/default/D80A-0F16 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6)
/mnt/media_rw/D80A-0F16 on /storage/D80A-0F16 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6)
/mnt/media_rw/D80A-0F16 on /mnt/runtime/read/D80A-0F16 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,mask=18)
/mnt/media_rw/D80A-0F16 on /mnt/runtime/write/D80A-0F16 type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,mask=18)
```

---

Can anyone think of a scenario I might be missing here which causes the file corruption?

**Edit:**

Another observation I have is, if I restart the device the filesystem seem to not get corrupt, which makes me think that for some reason the files  are not getting synced to disk correctly when unmounted?

What can I do to make sure the files are getting synced to disk when unmounted?

Comment: Please do not post console/text output as screenshot. You can simply mark the text and copy it to clipboard. Then edit your question and paste the text in it.

Comment: External storage is exposed as emulated filesystem in isolated mount namespace for every app. So you need to take into account mount propagation. Filesystem must be un-mounted from all namespaces. Or all apps (their native processes) must be killed before un-mounting in root mount namespace. Usually `vold` handles all of this nitty-gritty automatically. You can verify, however.

Comment: Irfan, Its only one app that does the mount/unmount using storage manager APIs. but other apps which have permission to read /write  are notified with a broadcast to let them know of the storage and a 'sync' is performed before actual unmount.Is that a clean way to do it? At the moment I am looking at corruption of one set of 4 files written by one application, they are small files and disk is not unmounted when app is writing them. but still once in awhile I am finding one or more of the files getting corrupted, pars of one fie ends up in another or parts of file is missing.. etc